# How do I invoke a macro variable inside the quoted string of a libname statement in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a libname that varies from year to year and I wanted to make a program that automatically adjusts for this. But in order for everything to work I have to have invoke a macro inside of the quoted string in a libname statement. How do I do this?

```
%macro srvyr;

data work.whatever;

length srvyr $4.;

srvyr = (left(year(date()))-1);


srvyr2 = "'C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\sas\d"||srvyr||"a1'";


run;

%mend;

%srvyr;  

/*Everything above sets configures the pathname the way I need it*/
```

**I want to then run this:**

```
libname stuff &srvyr;run;
```

**as if it were**

```
libname stuff 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\sas\d2010a1';
run;
```

How do I do this right?

Answer (score 4):

Does is always have to be the previous year, or do you want to base it on a value in a dataset. You don't need macro to solve this.

The shortest method to get last year is as follows

```
libname stuff "C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\sas\d%eval(%sysfunc(year(%sysfunc(date())))-1)a1";
```

and if you want to break it up to make it more readable it could be like this

```
%let lastyear = %eval(%sysfunc(year(%sysfunc(date())))-1);
%let libpath = C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\sas\d&lastyear.a1;

libname stuff "&libpath";
```

Comment: Perfect answer from Laurent.

Here is a variation on calculating last year with macro functions that shows the use of the intnx function for date arithmetic, nested %sysfunc's and the second parameter to %sysfunc that allow you to format the result.

`%let lastyear = %sysfunc(intnx(year,%sysfunc(today()),-1),year4.);`

I find the combination of intnx and formats provides lots of flexibility to do a very wide variety of date manipulation in a small amount of code.

Comment: Ah I was wondering how to do an intnx with the year! I see you used the %sysfunc in front of it which looks important. Perhaps that is why when I tried it I couldn't get it to work because I didn't know to use %sysfunc.    Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks Laurent de Walick, this worked perfectly I have never used the %eval or the %sysfunc but I can begin to see why I should have. I am going to play around with these more in my sas code. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

`call symput` is your friend. Put the following inside the data step, after creating the variable srvyr2:

```
call symput('srvyr_path', srvyr2);
```

and then outside the macro,

```
libname stuff &srvyr_path;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info Hong Ooi. Call Symput('Hong_Ooi', friend); libname thanks &Hong_Ooi;  I think when I tried this I had the syntax backwards inside the parentheses!!

Comment: call symputx let's you specify the symbol table (local or global) explicitly. It is often preferable to symput.  It trims blanks for you as well so no need to trim(left()) the input.